# Segurança dos dados em uma api em plumber R

Tags: r, web-service, api, segurança

Amigos, criei um api com plumber para transferências de dados de clientes, ou seja dados confidenciais. No endereço da url vai o ip da minha máquina. A respeito da segurança dos dados trafegados e da proteção do meu computador, qual o risco que corro? Obrigado